# ProviderName does not match the Provider Name given in the add-in listing metadata

Tags: office-js, outlook-web-addins, outlook-web-app, office-store

Currently we are trying to publish our Outlook Adding y Office Store, however it was rejected due to the following reason:

**1120.3.6.22** ProviderName Match
The ProviderName element in the manifest does not match the Provider Name given in the add-in listing metadata.
Please update the manifest and/or metadata with the correct Provider Name and re-submit your offer.

We have included in the  manifest entry the name of our organization (just as is shown in our developer account info).

¿Where can I check the ProviderName for my developer account?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The provider name in the submitted manifest must match the submitters provider name. Please ensure they are the same before resubmitting.